# phpmyadmin CSV import memory issues

Tags: csv, memory-leaks, import, phpmyadmin, memory-limit

We use a central phpMyAdmin instance to manage many remote mysql servers.  One of the developers has come to me with an issue with importing a CSV in to mysqld database using phpMyAdmin import tools since updating phpMyAdmin to 4.0.9.
Here's the details: -

```
phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.0.9deb1.lucid~ppa.1 is used to centrally manage a number mysql instances including the developers Developer VM's

MySQL Database: /usr/libexec/mysqld  Ver 5.5.36 for Linux on x86_64 (remote host)

Apache2:
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:42:25

PHP:
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19 

CSV file sample in this case is 2.75MB in size.
```

I started with the default php.ini memory limit 10MB which I end up increasing out to 256MB while debugging this issue.  When memory_limit was less that 128MB or less the following error message was received:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 203461 bytes) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugins/import/ImportCsv.class.php on line 473
```

I managed to get around this part of the problem after increasing this too 256MB the error changed to

```
Exceeds Max Allowed Packet for MySQL
```

I believe I have localised the issue to phpMyAdmin by performing a LOAD DATA IN FILE from the terminal manually importing data from mysql CLI using the same SOURCE and TARGET hosts there was no problem and data is import correctly.

if we use phpMyAdmin on the localhost of the mysql server (Version information: 4.1.11) I got a different problem with message stating the database has gone away which I have put down to query taking too long to run for similar reasons.

I guess what I am thrown by is "How the hell does a 2.75MB CSV manage to balloon out to just under 256MB when handled by phpMyAdmin"?  Memory leak perhaps?

I have a good look around on the internet and am struggling to come up with some decent answers here.

Perhaps in need to log a bug with phpMyAdmin?????

Has any one else encountered this problem and have a solution?